# calendar through userform in excel 2013

Tags: vba, calendar, excel-2013, userform

I created a userform with Start Date, End Date, Received Date as labels and each label with a textbox. Addin for calendar control cannot be installed due to admin rights.

My search ends with installing addin to get the Calendar control 6.0 installed which fails with error "Access is denied" on my machine.

My userform works fine, user has to input date manually. 
How to do I get a calendar popup here or any other suggestions to enter the date by just a click on Excel 2013 running on 64bit.

Appreciate your time here. Thank you.

Comment: I resolved it myself. Thank you so much :)
How do I close this?

Comment: Post the answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Function my_date_selection(ByVal d As Variant) As Date
If Not IsDate(d) Then GoTo L1 'Exit Function

If IsDate(d) = True Then
Load calendar
calendar.SelectedDayNumber = Day(d)
calendar.SelectedMonthNumber = Month(d)
calendar.SelectedYearNumber = Year(d)
End If

L1:
calendar.Show

If calendar.SelectedDayNumber = 0 And _
 calendar.SelectedMonthNumber = 0 And _
 calendar.SelectedYearNumber = 0 Then


 my_date_selection = Date
 ' user click on the cancel button in the calendar control therefore do nothing
Else
 my_date_selection = DateSerial(calendar.SelectedYearNumber, _
                           calendar.SelectedMonthNumber, _
                           calendar.SelectedDayNumber)
'   my_date_selection = Format(my_date_selection, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
End If
'   If my_date_selection < Date Then MsgBox "Invalid Date.":     GoTo l1
Unload calendar

End Function
```